# Retain memory leak in iphone menuitem

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-leaks, retain

How to solve memory leak in this:

```
NSArray *keyboard = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:menuPath] objectForKey:@"Menu"];
[self setMenuItems:keyboard];
[keyboard release];
```

setMenuItems is defined in header file.

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *menuItems;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:menuPath]; 
self.menuItems = [dict objectForKey:@"Menu"]; 
[dict release];
```

And in your dealloc method

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [menuItems release], menuItems = nil;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In dealloc method

```
- (void)dealloc
{
self.menuItems = nil;
[super dealloc];
}

NSArray *keyboard = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:menuPath] objectForKey:@"Menu"];
self.menuItems = keyboard; 
[keyboard release];
```